# Mock JPA repository in a test which uses MockMvc in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have the following controller :

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {
    if(userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
        return new ResponseEntity(new ApiResponse(false, "Username is already taken!"),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    if(userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
        return new ResponseEntity(new ApiResponse(false, "Email Address already in use!"),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    // Creating user's account
    User user = new User(signUpRequest.getName(), signUpRequest.getUsername(),
            signUpRequest.getEmail(), signUpRequest.getPassword());

    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

    Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.ROLE_USER)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new AppException("User Role not set."));

    user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(userRole));

    User result = userRepository.save(user);

    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
            .fromCurrentContextPath().path("/api/users/{username}")
            .buildAndExpand(result.getUsername()).toUri();

    return ResponseEntity.created(location).body(new ApiResponse(true, "User registered successfully"));
}
```

In the above code, I am using a JPA repo to get role names from the database and use them for my user, if they exist.

I am trying to test this using the following test :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = VlmSpringBootApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AuthControllerTests
{
    @Autowired
    private AuthController authController;

    @MockBean
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(authController);
    }

    @Test
    public void createUserTest() throws Exception {

        User newTestUser = new User();
        newTestUser.setName("testUserA");
        newTestUser.setUsername("testUserA");
        newTestUser.setEmail("testUserA@testing.com");
        newTestUser.setPassword("superSecretStuff");

        Role testRole = new Role();
        testRole.setName(RoleName.ROLE_USER);

        Optional<Role> optional = Optional.of(testRole);

        Set<Role> roles = Collections.EMPTY_SET;
        roles.add(optional.get());
        newTestUser.setRoles(roles);

        when(roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.ROLE_USER)).thenReturn(optional);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(newTestUser);
        mockMvc.perform(put("/api/auth/signup")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(json))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

When I run this test, I get the following error :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.add(AbstractCollection.java:262)
    at com.me.myapp.controller.AuthControllerTests.createUserTest(AuthControllerTests.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

All I want to do is have it be so that in the code that is being tested, we mock up that repo call to get the roles, and from there I will be able to continue on.

Comment: (1) Use `Collections.emptySet()` instead of `EMPTY_SET`, and (2) that particular set is immutable--use a regular set implementation or `Set.of`.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this one myself! I needed to be doing

```
@InjectMocks
```

on the controller, rather that `@Autowired`.